# Derivatives of a quadratic form.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I have this quadratic function

$$\bar x^T Q \bar x$$

and I need to find the first and second derivative. My question is how can I do that by just using the matrix from? I've been multiplying $Q$ by $\bar x$ and then taking it back to matrix form but this is too impractical. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not algebra precalculus when it is a calculus question

Answer (score 7):

I’ll assume $Q$ is symmetric. Let $f(x) = x^T Qx$. If $h$ is a small vector then

\begin{align}
f(x+h) &= (x+h)^TQ(x+h) \\
&= x^TQx + 2x^TQh + h^TQh \\
&\approx x^TQx + 2 x^TQh. 
\end{align}
Comparing this with $f(x+h) \approx f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T h$ reveals that $\nabla f(x) = 2Qx$. The Hessian is the derivative of the gradient so $Hf(x) = 2Q$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $J:X^n\to Y$ is a $n$-linear map between Banach spaces, then

$$
\partial J(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)(r_1,\ldots ,r_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n J(x_1,\ldots ,x_{k-1},r_k,x_{k+1},\ldots ,x_n)
$$

Now as $Q$ is bilinear then with the map $f:X\to X^2,\, x\mapsto (x,x)$ then the chain rule gives

$$
\partial [Q(x,x)]y=\partial [(Q\circ f)(x)]y=\partial Q(x,x)\partial f(x)y=\partial Q(x,x)(y,y)=Q(x,y)+Q(y,x)
$$

And if $Q$ is symmetric then $Q(x,y)+Q(y,x)=2Q(x,y)$.